# storing image in Db using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Im developing art gallery which needs 1000s of images to be uploaded so inserting images in DB won't be feasible. so i want to give link of folder inside db where ultimately images should get stored. plz help.

Answer (score 0):

> so inserting images in DB won't be
>   feasible

Why? Works very nicely. Especially with 2008 where you then dump them into a file system store again transparently.

I have a datas store where I store about 500gb of binary information all stored within the database. No issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are using SQL 2008 you can use the FileStream mechanism, which actually stores the images as files on disk, but can be returned in sql results, so the data is still relational.

But answer aside, there's nothing wrong with storing 1000's of images in the database. But worst case, just store the string link if you really want.. its just that process is a little archaic.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the DB that you're using I suppose (you didn't mentioned which you're using)

You can always store a relative path to the image file.
For example you might store images at UNC location of: **\\YOUR_SERVER\myApplication\images\image1.png**

-> the relative path would just be **\myApplication\images\image1.png**

(By storing just the relative path to the file, you're isolating the possiblity that you might change the server location in future.)

If you are using Sql Server 2008, then checkout the FileStream feature. More background info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx).

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might also considered storing images in the cloud (eg Amazon S3)... Just start thinking of how you would model this, so you could potentially change the file storage strategy in the future but with minimal impact/change to code.

Answer (score 0):

One of my sites stores all user uploaded images in sql server and it works great.  The only problem I can see if you are using shared hosting where you don't get a large database. Otherwise I think its a great option.